# C linked list; max frequency node in a list

Tags: c, linked-list, frequency

Struct: n represents the data of node, f is the frequency of a node and next is a pointer to next node. I wrote a recursive function that adds nodes at the end of the linked list. I have to write a function that counts numbers of occurrences of nodes and to find a node with biggest frequency.

```
struct node
{
int n;
int f;
struct node* next;
};
```

Recursive add function:

```
void add(struct node** hPtr, int n)
{

if(*hPtr==NULL) {
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->n=n;
    new_node->f=0; 
    new_node->next=NULL;
    *hPtr = new_node;
}
else{
    add(&((*hPtr)->next),n);
}
}
```

Print function:

```
void print(struct node* head)
{
if (head==NULL) return;
while(head!=NULL){
    printf("%d (%d)->",head->n,head->f);
    head = head->next;
}
}
```

Function that counts f of nodes, which doesn't work:

```
void count(struct node* head)
{
if (head==NULL) return;
struct node* temp = head;
while(head!=NULL)
{
    if (head->n == temp->n){
        head->f++;
        temp=temp->next;
    } else temp=temp->next;
}

return count(head->next);
}
```

Comment: In `add()`, `if(*hPtr=NULL)`... I guess that's a typo ?  You may be better off counting up the frequency during the `add()` -- presumably you don't really want to add a node for an `n` which already has a node ?

Comment: It was a typo.. How can I count the frequency during the add function? Sorry I am a beginner takes a bit more time  to do a simple task.

Comment: If in `add()` you find `(*hPtr)->n == n`, presumably you don't need to add a new node, you just need to `(*hPtr)->f += 1` ?

Comment: I understood it

Comment: FWIW: the recursion in `add()` is a waste of time and stack-space -- but your compiler may know that and save you from yourself (see _Tail Call Optimization_.  If there are a lot of numbers, and a few are more frequent than the rest, then when you find `(*hPtr)->n == n` you could move that node to the front of the list -- which will cluster frequent nodes at the front, speeding up the more frequent ones.